# Estatísticas da língua portuguesa

Tags: uso-de-palavras, vocabulário, classificação-de-palavras

Onde podemos encontrar estatísticas da língua portuguesa?

Como exemplo, dentro do universo de palavras catalogadas (pelos dicionários): Quantidade de palavras por classe gramatical, quantidades de palavras com certas características como terminadas com certas letras, ou de certas origens, quantidade de verbos irregulares, verbos por sufixo, palavras por quantidade de sílabas, e assim por diante.

Existem estas estatísticas ?

Comment: Vários dicionários dão algumas dessa informações. Agora não te posso ver isso: tou na praia, e deixei os dicionários a descansar em casa :)

Answer (score 2):

A [Linguateca](http://www.linguateca.pt/) disponibiliza uma quantidade impressionante de recursos, incluindo uma [grande quantidade de dados](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/ordenador.php) sobre frequência e ordenamento.

Várias páginas listam estatísticas mais simples (como frequência de letras). [Esta página](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~pedro/cientificos/Cripto/) lista e também disponibiliza algoritmos para a obtenção das frequências relativas das letras, comprimento médio das palavras, etc. Outras frequências são dadas [neste site](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~rvr/naulas/tabelasPT/), e também [neste](https://www.sttmedia.com/characterfrequency-portuguese).

A [Wordnet-PT/PULO](http://wordnet.pt/) (Portuguese Unified Lexical Ontology) oferece uma modesta lista com cerca de 17 mil substantivos, 8 mil verbos, 6 mil adjetivos e 800 advérbios.

[image]

Um trabalho relacionado, que pode ser de interesse, é o artigo [Análise quantitativa da freqüência dos fonemas e
estruturas silábicas portuguesas](http://www.gel.org.br/estudoslinguisticos/edicoesanteriores/4publica-estudos-2007/sistema06/02.PDF) (pdf) de Viaro e Guimarães-Filho.