# Fazer download (importar) lista de substantivos existentes na língua portuguesa

Tags: substantivos

Onde eu posso encontrar uma lista importável (formato txt, etc) de "todos (o número mais próximo do atual de)" substantivos da língua portuguesa?

Comment: No site https://paste.ubuntu.com/25270939/ há alguns.

Comment: Grato @ValdeirPsr. Eu havia visto esta lista hoje. Mas ainda é incompleta. Tenho tentado exportar de http://wordnet.pt/download como sugerido nesta questão https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5037/6563 a qual já aponta mais de 17 mil substantivos e não 5400 como em https://paste.ubuntu.com/25270939/. Mas ainda não tive tempo de instalar as ferramentas para compilar os dados deste arquivo SQL.

Comment: Sinceramente não sei se tem o que pretende, mas se fosse eu dava uma olhada neste projeto: [WebJspell](https://natura.di.uminho.pt/webjspell/jsolhelp.pl)

Comment: Eu encontrei uma lista de todas as palavras neste projeto https://github.com/pythonprobr/palavras/blob/master/palavras.txt e usando regex eliminei todas as palavras terminadas em "er" ou "ar"  que são caracterizantes de verbos apenas. Aqui está esta minha lista https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DiegoBneiNoah/listapalavrassemarouer/master/newmix

Comment: Você conseguiu encontrar a lista que queria? Se tiver conseguido e ainda a tiver, poderia me passar? Também estou precisando.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about resources not the language.

Comment: Já ouviu falar de dicionários? Devo dizer que essa pergunta me irrita. Os dicionários **são listas de palavras**.